# mageia: Dual Monitor with single video card and touchscreen and mouse pointer not working right

Tags: bash, mouse, multiple-monitors, cursor-position, mageia

I am not sure if I am allowed to post this question here. If it needs to be moved, admin can do so.

I have a computer with a single video card with dual HDMI, DVI-D and other ports. I use mainly the HDMIs and the DVI-D port. I connected primary monitor on the DVI-D and the secondary monitor on one of the HDMI port. In the Mageia 5 display settings, I am able to **Unify the monitors**. At boot, primary monitor comes up first and then followed by the secondary monitor. They both are mirrored or show the same Mageia 5 desktop. At this point, if you move the mouse pointer with your mouse around the primary screen as long as you you don't move the mouse pointer beyond your monitor's resolution, mouse pointer works. But as soon as you move the pointer beyond the resolution, mouse pointer totally disappears and the only way to get it back is to reboot the computer.

Second issue I have is that on the secondary monitor which has touchscreen capability, whenever I touch the screen with my finger and move the mouse pointer it is OFFSET from my finger location on the screen to the RIGHT and the mouse pointer moves EXPONENTIALLY. Closer your finger is to the left the of the screen, the closer the mouse pointer is to your finger's location.

This I can't figure out. I have used **xinput_calibrator** successfully, but it didn't fix the mouse pointer. And I thought of writing my own script or shell program that would run in the back restricting the mouse pointer to monitor only or the desktop, but that would mess up the mouse pointer when using the mouse. I've been looking on the Internet for some sort of hints or clues, but nothings helped so far.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Not clear why you have tagged this with `bash`. This is clearly a harware (or hardware/software interace) issue. Don't expect an admin will move it to the right forum. You should delete here and repost a Q that follows the guidelines of the forum. If you can edit your Q to include a block of copy/pasteable test code, then your Q might be on topic here. Good luck.